# If I pull data from an API and save it in a variable, does it hit the API every time I call that variable?

Tags: python

I'm grabbing a list from a website using their API and saving it as variable "playlistNames". In a later function when I call "playlistNames" to manipulate the data, is it making another API call? or is the data just stored locally in the "playlistNames" variable?

Sorry for such a silly question, I can't seem to google this properly.

Comment: As long as you properly assigned the variable the API response will be stored in memory.

Comment: so if my API request was literally something like playlistNames = (API REQUEST HERE) then I'm good to go?

Comment: Within the same script, yes, unless you are calling it as a method. We need to see the whole code or at least the relevant parts to give a definite answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you saved the API response to a variable, it won't call the API every time you access that variable.

```
r = requests.get("https://google.com")
print(r.text) # doesn't call again...
print(r.status_code) # doesn't call again...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the entire script where you wrote the API request and the execution passes through it every time you run it, it will call it. Otherwise it will run it from the saved variable assuming you are on the same kernel.

Comment: What does "same kernel" mean in this context? Did you mean same process?